# Rotate image 90 degrees explanation

Tags: java, image, rotation

So I managed to get an image to rotate 90 degrees by using my code for 180 and messing about basically but Im still very confused on what the code actually does and how it does it. I understand the rotate 180 but not the rotate 90 with the code below. Can any explain this to me?

```
OFImage image1 = new OFImage(image);

for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); ++x) {
for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); ++y) {
image.setPixel(y, x, image1.getPixel(image.getWidth() - x - 1, y));
```

Comment: What is `OFImage` class??

Comment: its the image type, like bufferedImage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have commented your code

```
OFImage image1 = new OFImage(image); // create a copy of `image`

for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); ++x) { // loop through each column of pixels in original presumably from left to right
for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); ++y) { // loop through each cell of the column presumably from top to bottom
image.setPixel(y, x, image1.getPixel(image.getWidth() - x - 1, y)); // here you have swapped the x and y coordinates and you are putting in the pixel from the copy that is at width - x - 1, y
```

So when x = 0 (column) and y = 0 (row), you are putting in a copy of the pixel from (W= image.width - 1, y) (last pixel in first row) into (0,0) so (W,0) => (0,0)
Then when x = 0 and y = 1 it is (W, 1) => (1, 0), then (W, 2) => (2, 0)

At the start of your loops, you are reading from the rightmost column, and writing to the topmost row.

Comment: There is a .rotate90() method on the OFImage class that probably does this more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to describe the process in detail to be honest, but it's just using maths (obviously), to swap each pixel individually with the appropriate alternative pixel, to give the effect of a 90 degree rotation.

To help me understand it, I drew 3x3 and 4x4 grids, and labelled each cell, simulating pixels. And simply used the method "setPixel" with its parameters as an equation, and passed each pixel/co-ordinate through it to work out the result. I'd suggest doing the same, since it's probably the best method to understanding how the method works properly.